# IQueryable concatenate expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

Suppose I have a Magazine class, with an enum property that describes the subscription period (Monthly, Bimonthly, Quarterly,...). The values in the enum are chosen thus, that some calculations can be made easy

Using Entity FrameWork I have a `DbContext` with a `DbSet<Magazine>`

```
enum SubscriptionPeriodType
{
    Monthly = 1,
    Bimonthly = 2,
    Quarterly = 3,
    Annual = 12,
};
class Magazine
{
    public SubscriptionPeriodType SubscriptionPeriodType {get; set;}
    ...
}
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Magazine> Magazines {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Given a date within a year, I want to know the first day and the last day of the subscription period. For example, if I have a quarterly subscription period, ant it is 15 May 2016, then the first day of the subscription period 1 April 2016, The last day is 30 June 2016.

The calculations are as follows (in baby steps)

```
Period CalculatePeriod(DateTime date) 
{
    SubscriptionPeriodType subscriptionPeriodType = dbContext.Magazines
        .Where(...)
        .Select(magazine => magazine.SubscriptionPeriodType;
    int periodLength = (int)subscriptionPeriodType;
    int periodNr = (date.Month - 1) / periodLength;
    // quarters are numbered 0..3

    int periodStartMonth = periodNr * periodLength + 1;
    // quarters start in months 1 / 4 / 7 / 10
    DateTime startPeriod = new DateTime(date.Year, periodStartMonth, 1);
    DateTime nextPeriod = startPeriod.AddMonths(periodLength);
    return new Period()
    {
        FirstDay = startPeriod,
        LastDay = nextPeriod.AddDays(-1),
    }
```

Although this function can be used in `IEnumerable.Select` it cannot be used in `IQueryable.Select`. You can not create a Block statement in an `IQueryable.Select`.

However, the calculations to get to `StartPeriod` and `NextPeriod` are fairly simple. I'd like to create an Expression tree that I can give to my Select statement.

**What I've done so far**
I know how to create the first few statements as Expressions:

```
Expression<Func<Magazine, SupbscriptionPeriodType>> e1 = 
     magazine => magazine.SubscriptionPeriodType;
Expression<Func<SubscriptionPeriodType, int>> PeriodLength = s => (int)s;
Expression<Func<DateTime, int, int>> PeriodNr = 
    (date, periodLength) => (date.Month - 1) / periodLength;

// etc.
```

But how to concatenate these expressions into one Expression and how to call it in the Select?

```
var result = dbContext.Magazines
    .Where(...)
    .Select(magazine => ConcatenatedExpression.... )
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to have the select to work within the `IQueryable`?  I would think you'd want to do that logic on the query side.  If that's the case, you could apply the Where clause to your IQueryable, then convert the materialized result to an enumerable, e.g. `myMagazinesQueryable.Where(...).AsEnumerable().Select(magazine => CalculatePeriod(magazine, date))`.  You'd just need to rewrite `CalculatePeriod` as a pure function).

Comment: Yes MikeBridge, this would be a possibility. I'v also seen that I could put the statements in several Select statements after each other. This results in an SQL statement with temp variables similar to the statements I want. However, Select after Select after Select does not look very professional, and it is difficult to understand by others.. Besides I want to master the skill of creating Expressions

Comment: In my experience, writing small expressions is useful to create composable and reusable Where clauses, but I suspect that writing a Select clause with Expressions would introduce a lot of unnecessary complexity.  Given the choice of running the Select on the DB or in C# I don't think you gain anything by choosing to run the date logic in the database via an expression tree (if it's even possible---I kind of doubt it would work).  It just adds more code and another level of indirection.